# Map from a topological space to the pushout is continuous?

Tags: general-topology, self-learning

Recently, I have encountered a question:

Prove that the map $f_Y:Y\rightarrow Y\coprod_XZ$ defined by $f(y)=[y]$ is continuous.

However, when I tried to prove it using the open sets definition of continuity, it seems really complicated as I need to write down the set definition and I failed to do so. Is there any way to prove this more effectively?

(Off-topic: What are the best way to study topology? It seems drawing graphs is pretty useful but sometimes it is hard to draw a picture for concepts like continuity. Do we just hard-memorise the definitions?)

Comment: This is a composite $Y \to Y \amalg Z \to Y\amalg_X Z$.  The first is continuous by design, and the second is a quotient map.

Comment: Oh. I thought it was a direct mapping... Then everything make sense now!

Comment: Well, it is, but it is also expressible as a composition.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Randall comments, $f_Y = \pi \circ  j_Y$, where $j_Y : Y \to Y \coprod Z$ is the canonical injection (which is trivially continuous) and $\pi : Y \coprod Z \to Y \coprod_X  Z$ is the quotient map (which is continuous by definition).

It seems that you know the concept of a pushout, and this construction assigns to a pair of continuous maps $\phi_Y: X \to Y$ and $\phi_Z: X \to Z$ a commutative diagram of spaces and continuous maps
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X  @>{\phi_Y}>> Y \\
@V{\phi_Z}VV @V{f_Y}VV \\
Z @>{f_Z}>> Y \coprod_X  Z\end{CD}

with a certain universal property. Thus $f_Y$ is continuous by the concept of the pushout.

A standard *explicit construction* is
$$Y \coprod_X  Z = (Y \coprod Z)/\phi_Y(x) \sim \phi_Z(x),\\
f_Y(y) =[y], f_Z(z) =[z] .$$
Perhaps your question concerns this construction and asks why $f_
Y, f_Z$ are continuous?